# Unable to connect PostgreSQL(pgAdmin 4) to the Google Cloud Platform

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, cloud, pgadmin-4

I have instance on Google Cloud Platform and I'm trying to connect it to the **pgAdmin 4**.

So here is my **postgresql.conf**
[image]

So I've tried the following:

I've wrote the instance ip as well as the username and password.

And I get the following error:
[image]

I've added my IP Address on cloud instance, but this didn't help as well.

[image]

Is there something else what I can try?

Comment: Everything that needed to be done has been done correctly so tough to say what is causing this. I would recommend you try connecting via command line first as instructed in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-admin-ip#connect) to check what comes out of it. Let me know if you are able to connect after that.

Comment: 'timeout expired` in this sort of generally means a firewall blocked the connection. Have you opened port 5432 to external access?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thank you very much, my port wasn't open. So I opened it manually, if someone needs links on how to open the port [here](http://www.project-open.com/en/howto-postgresql-port-secure-remote-access) it is.

Comment: Just remember that you have now opened the database to public access as determined by the IP's you allow in. Make sure your pg_hba.conf and role security are sufficient to deal with this.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver do you have maybe any link for that so I can see how to configure it or ?

Comment: For pg_hba.conf see [Client Auth](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html). For roles see [Create Role](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createrole.html) and follow the links to further information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as a community wiki as this is based on the comments shared by @AdrianKlaver:

Given that you get a `timeout expired` error, which generally means a firewall blocked the connection, this is likely to be an issue on the port 5432 not being open to external access, so if you change that this might work.

**NOTE**: Just remember that you once you do this you will have opened the database to public access as determined by the IP's you allow in. Make sure your pg_hba.conf and role security are sufficient to deal with this. You can find more information on how to set this up by following both of this documenation links for [Client Auth](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) and to [Create Roles](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createrole.html)